# Final members with multiple constructor

Tags: java, constructor, final

I have a class like this.

```
    public class AuditEvent {

     private final String m_timeStamp;
     private final String m_userName;
     private int m_moduleId;
     private int m_actionId;
     private final String m_objectName;
     private final String m_loggedInUserHostOrIP;

   public AuditEvent() {
    // No content
   }

  public AuditEvent(String timeStamp, String userName, String loggedInUserHostOrIP, String objectName) {

  if (StringUtils.nullOrEmpty(timeStamp)) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("The timeStamp field is not supplied");
  }
  if (StringUtils.nullOrEmpty(timeStamp)) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("The userName field is not supplied");
  }
  if (null == objectName) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("The objectName field is not supplied");
  }
  if (null == loggedInUserHostOrIP) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("The loggedInUserHostOrIP field is not supplied");
  }
  m_timeStamp = timeStamp;
  m_userName = userName;
  m_loggedInUserHostOrIP = loggedInUserHostOrIP;
  m_objectName = objectName;
 }
```

But this gives an error that the final field m_userName may not have been initialized. It works if I don't have the empty constructor. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `m_timeStamp` as `final` but you have never initialized it in the empty constructor.

Every constructor should declare the variable if it's final, not just one. Or you can initialize it after declaring it, which will be valid aswell. eg

```
private final String m_timeStamp = "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill in all `final` fields in every constructor. Calling another constructor as follows helps:

```
public AuditEvent() {
    this("" /*timeStamp*/, "" /*userName*/, "" /*loggedInUserHostOrIP*/, "" /*objectName*/);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `final` field **has to** be initialized as the object is fully build and that the constructor has returned.

While here `final` fields are never valued :

```
public AuditEvent() {
// No content
}
```

So if you invoke this constructor and not the other one you violate the `final` constraints. Whereas the compilation error.

If the no arg constructor makes sense in your use case you could still define field initializers such as :

```
 private final String m_timeStamp = "...";
 private final String m_userName = "...";
```

Or as alternative chain the the no arg constructor to the args constructor :

```
public AuditEvent() {
  this("...", "...", ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java final variables must be initialized only once, before or inside constructor.